# How to Construct a Perspective Projection With 4 Vanishing Points

Tags: opengl, graphics, mathematics

Is it possible to construct a projection matrix which will create a perspective with four (or more) vanishing points?

This question have an OpenGL tag, but general insights are welcomed as well.

[image: An example of 4-vanishing point perspective I have found on google]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To the simple question of "can you use a projection matrix" to do this, the answer is no. The reason is that a matrix multiplication can only result in an linear or affine transform that maps lines to lines, whereas you're looking to map a line to a curve.

To the question of "how do I implement a fisheye projection", see:

#### [How do I create a wide-angle / fisheye lens with HLSL?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20626/how-do-i-create-a-wide-angle-fisheye-lens-with-hlsl)